# SetHasFixedSizetrue shows error How to solve it

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with firebase backend. I want to show latest item on top in my view. I just use setStackFromEnd(true); in my layoutmanager but its show error jutst like this

[image: See Image]

My minimum SDK Version is 16
and I used to <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

and this is my java code

```
MCC=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Troll");
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.TrollID_recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 1));

        LoadData(categoryId);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should store latest item first in recycleadapterList then your other items add to list.
because recycleadapter show items like list item position